# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index n out of bounds en Java

Tags: java

Tengo este array declarado:

```
        int[] asientos[] = {
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
```

y lo estoy recorriendo para mostrarlo por consola de la siguiente manera

```
public static void dibujarAsientos(int[] asientos[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= asientos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < asientos[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(asientos[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

me lo dibuja tal y como yo quiero (simulando los asientos de un avión), pero al final me sale el error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10
```

¿Qué puede ser?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que el primer nivel del array solo llega hasta la posición 9 y en el bucle `for` del método `dibujarAsientos` le estás indicando que aumente la variable mientras sea menor o igual a la longitud. Como el método `length` cuenta la longitud, empieza en 1 no en 0, así que tiene siempre un valor más que las posiciones.

Solución: cambia el operador del primer bucle `for` `<=` por `<`. Así:

```
public static void dibujarAsientos(int[] asientos[]) {
for (int i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 0; j < asientos[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(asientos[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
}
```